# Why does the Neo4j browser display two different version numbers?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

It says 3.0.1 in the About pane and 3.2.0 in the DB Information pane. 
[image: Two different version numbers]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3.0.1 is the version of [Neo4j Browser](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/), the tool you are using to query the database and visualize results.

3.2.0 is the version of Neo4j Graph Database you are using.